# My alert is not showing in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

this is my PostController.php,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Depress;
use App\Http\Requests;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function createPost(Request $request)
    {

        $depress = new Depress();
        $depress->depression = $request['depression'];
        if($request['name'])
            $depress->name = $request['name'];
        else
            $depress->name = "Depressed Anonymous";
        $depress->save();
        \Session::flash('info','Success');
        return redirect()->route('home');

    }
}
```

And This is my alert.blade.php,

```
@if(Session::has('info'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        {{ Session::get('info') }}
    </div>
    <br>
@endif
```

And, I have included it in my layout.blade.php

But, no alert shows up...

thanks in advance

Comment: The code looks like it should work.  Maybe you need to look at where you are including alert.blade.php and check the HTML source to see if the HTML is being placed.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use session flash. use the laravel way,

**In your controller**

```
return Redirect::to('home')->with('success', 'You message here.');
```

**In your view**

```
@if (isset($success))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          {!! $success !!}. 
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: The redirect with does use session flash.https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data.  You're mixing up view() and redirect() I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`\Session::flash('info','Success');
return redirect()->route('home');`

To:

`return redirect()->route('home')->with(['info' => 'Success']);`

Basically, this will redirect you to home. So you need to make sure that in the action(function) that handles the route `home`, it returns to the view `alert.balde.php` or to a view that uses `alert.balde.php`. I tried doing this and it worked for me. Here is my code below:

in my controller:

```
public function home()
{
    return view('welcome');
}

public function test()
{
    return redirect()->route('home')->with(['info' => 'Success']);
}
```

And in my `welcome.blade.php`:

```
@if(Session::has('info'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        {{ Session::get('info') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

And I get to see 'Success' in the view.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use compact() on return and pass that variable in it. And you can access it as normal php variable in view.